# How to disable CSRF in a Sails application?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I'm trying to test a blueprint sails API, I configured its models and also **disabled CSRF** at `config/csrf.js` by setting `module.exports.csrf = false;`.

However when I try to reach an endpoint I'm always getting a:

**`403 Forbidden, Access token not present`**

What else should I take care of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should comment out the entire `config/csrf.js` module. Basically, it should be unavailable (`undefined`) and not returning anything. Also, make sure your `Controller` that controls the `route` isn't requiring any token.

PS: Make sure you're not talking about a session cookie that returns the `403`

Answer (score 3):

For future reference spelling out your environment, architecture, and related npm modules is important so that everyone is on the same page. You were using a non-sails.js core package, waterlock as you said in a comment after someone posted an answer, which implements security features. This would have been handy to know before having people attempt to answer your question.

Also, searching your entire app environment (if you have all packages installed locally, not globally via npm install -g) for the error or part of the error message can shed more light on what's going on to help pinpoint the issue.

Hope this helps!